# Rewriting query strings to slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website that's set up to load pages as `http://domain.tld?p=pagename`, and I'd like to have the pages accessible by `http://domain.tld/pagename` (simply because it's shorter and easier to direct people to).

I understand this can be done with `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess`, but I'm a bit nooby when it comes to server stuff. Is this advisable, and if so, how is it done?

(Oh, and the homepage has no query string, it's just `http://domain.tld` - I don't want this to break that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a little while since I played with apache configs, but you want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/([^/])/?  ?p=$1
```

The first part is a regex and the second part is a replacement much like you find in perl's `s/foo/bar/` construct (but of course there are a few differences from perl, because regex implementaions are always slightly different).

This will not match `http://domain.tld` or `http://domain.tld/` because `([^/])` is not satisfied, and not optional. The `/?` at the end of the regex is to handle `http://domain.tld/pagename` and `http://domain.tld/pagename/` equally (if you want to do that)

Note that my code above will not necessarily work if there are other parameters being passed on the query string, but you didn't ask for that...

You should be aware that url rewriting can get very complicated to maintain as the pages begin to have additional query string parameters or you want `/area/pagename` etc. This added complexity will eventually result in you spending a lot of time reading this page:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Perhaps it's worth it... only you know the answer to that questiong :)

Comment: There are one or two pages with forms that add additional parameters to the query string, so I guess ideally I'd support those too. It's not even essential that I `get` the forms, I could `post` them instead, but I'd prefer to get them if possible. I do need to learn how `mod_rewrite` works, but it's slightly daunting at the moment.

Comment: Wait, would the `[QSA]` flag do it?

Comment: Actually get is usually wrong for forms. GET requests should be "safe" in that they do not change state on the server. HTTP spec specifies that PUT is for idempotent mutating requests (not very common except int REST architecture) and POST is for things that change state and can have a different effect for the same submitted data (such as charging your credit card repeatedly resulting in lower and lower bank balances :) ). `[QSA]` would likely be involved if you wish to preserve parameters, but watch out for `http://example.com/foo?a=b` ==> `http://example.com/?p=foo?a=b`

Comment: The forms just do arithmetic and logic operations, and return output that the user may want to link to - none of the data is anything important, it's just a fancy calculator. The ability to link to the output is useful enough, I think, to justify GET. Anyway, I'll try your rewrite code. Thank you!